# retrieve a single object from firebase and output to a form for edit

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic-framework, ionic2, angularfire2

I am trying to retrieve a single object from firebase and output to a form for edit. I retrieve the single object with the below:

```
this.product = this.af.database.object('/products/'+ productId);
```

and try to output it into the template like this:

```
  <ion-item>
    <ion-label stacked>Date</ion-label>
    <ion-datetime [(ngModel)]="product.date" name="date" required></ion-datetime>
  </ion-item>
  <ion-item>
    <ion-label stacked>Content</ion-label>
    <ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="product.content" name="content" required></ion-input>
  </ion-item>
  <ion-item>
    <ion-label stacked>Amount</ion-label>
    <ion-input type="number" [(ngModel)]="product.amount" name="amount"></ion-input>
  </ion-item>  
  <ion-item>
    <ion-label stacked>Category</ion-label>
    <ion-select type="text" [(ngModel)]="product.category" name="category" required>
      <ion-option>Book</ion-option>
      <ion-option>Baby</ion-option> 
      <ion-option>Clothing</ion-option> 
   </ion-select>
  </ion-item>  
</ion-list>
```

but the outputting to the form's fields doesn't work. Please help. I have tried applying the async operator like this

```
    <ion-input type="number" [(ngModel)]="product.amount" name="amount" value="product.amount | async"></ion-input>
```

but it doesn't work too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to implement `subscribe pattern` as shown below.

**service.ts**

```
 product : FirebaseObjectObservable<data-type>;

 constructor(public af: AngularFire) {}

  //get product
  getProduct(productId : string): FirebaseObjectObservable<data-type> {
    return this.product = this.af.database.object('/products/'+ productId);
  }
```

**page.ts**

```
public product: data-type;

constructor(public service: Service) {

    this.service.getProduct(productId).subscribe(snap => {
      this.product = snap;
    });
  }
```

Comment: I tried but it still doesn't work. Error message:
Uncaught (in promise): Error: InvalidPipeArgument: '[object Object]' for pipe 'AsyncPipe'
Error: InvalidPipeArgument: '[object Object]' for pipe 'AsyncPipe'

Comment: It's my pleasure :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this using current angularfire2 version like below

**controller.ts**

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
.......
product : Observable<any>;

constructor(public db: AngularFireDatabase) {
    this.product = this.db.object('/products/'+ productId)
        .snapshotChanges().map(res => {
            return res.payload.val();
        });
}
```

**html**

```
<ion-input type="number" value="{{(product|async)?.amount}}" [(ngModel)]="product.amount" name="amount"></ion-input>
```